# How to load a text file inside a JSON object within a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete function :-

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({

    data: {
```

The data JSON object will be responsible for giving the associated autocomplete values, the JSON key will be the autocomplete suggestions, and the JSON value will be null.

I don't want to manually enter values inside this JSON data like:-

```
data:{
    "Chocolate": null, 
    "Cake": null, 
    "Icecream": null, 
    "Pudding": null }
```

Instead, I want to fetch the JSON values from a text file, which will have these contents, so that I can just load the text file for this data JSON object, instead of having to manually enter it.

So, the list.txt file will have:-

```
           "Chocolate": null, 
            "Cake": null, 
            "Icecream": null, 
            "Pudding": null,
             "Cream:null
```

And I want to call this list.txt file inside JSON object data, something like:-

```
data: {
$.get('list.txt') }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: seems weird to use a txt file for JSON....

Comment: Are you using a server-side technology such as PHP? Also -- won't you have to manually enter the values into the text file?

Comment: @JacobMattison Actually I am using a bash script to add the semicolons and null, in the text file I will just have the names, and the script will convert it into JSON type text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.
Read data from text file with **ajax call** and **convert it into json object**.
It will work, but slight modification is needed with your text file as follows.

```
{
"Chocolate": "null", 
"Cake": "null", 
"Icecream": "null", 
"Cream":"null"
}
```

And your code will be as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "list.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $(".text").html(data);
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });
});
```

*If you don't want to modify the existing text file the below code will work.*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "list.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $(".text").html(data);
                var jsonData = JSON.parse("{"+data+"}");

                 $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
                     data:jsonData 
                 });  //to initialize autocomplete
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work, I think it actually needs to be put it inside the autcomplete function -  $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
data:{

Comment: For that get json data from the text file and store in in a global variable then pass that data inside autocomplete function. Try that also.

Comment: Or just consume data from text file and convert it into json outside autocomplete function then inside the success of ajax define that auto complete function and assign the json data to autocomplete's data.

Comment: How can I consume data from text file, is it $.get('text.html')? converting JSON, is it using JSON.parse? Should I store this in a variable to call it inside success function?

Comment: I have edited my answer just go-through that. `$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
                     data:jsonData 
                 });  //to initialize autocomplete` include this statement inside the success of ajax.

Comment: In-order to work with ajax call you should include this jQuery library  a `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`